# How to access angularJS controller as variables?

Tags: angularjs

How to define the value for controller as elements inside custom directive link function?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model=ctrl.inputvalue" my-directive/>
   <button value="submit" ng-disabled="ctrl.disable"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.inputValue = 'Qwerty';
});
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return{
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function(scope,elements,ngModelCtrl){
        //How to access ng-diasbled value here
        });
    }    
});
```

Comment: the javascript doesn't seem to be correct near the link-function. Is this a typo in the question or is this how your code looks? one `)` to much and the `;` should belong to the return statement

Comment: yes. its typo mistake. link:function(scope,elements,ngModelCtrl){
        //How to access ng-diasbled value here
        };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside link function write as **scope.ctrl.disable** to access the disable value.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
        return{
            require:'ngModel, ^myCtrl',
            link:function(scope,elements,ctrls){
                var d = ctrls[1].disable
            });
        }    
    });
```

Comment: When you set more than one required controller - they are passed as array into Link function. Order of this array is the same as in "require"

Comment: If we need to use ngModelCtrl,$parsers then it should be var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0]; right?

Comment: I am getting following error. Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.18/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel%2myCtrl&p1=myDirective

Comment: the controller(s) are the 4th parameter to the link function. the third one is attributes.

Comment: yes.  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls)

Comment: Edited answer to show correct requires for controller

Comment: still i am getting same error Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.18/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel%2C%20%5myCtrl&p1=myDirective